# How do I connect to MySQL database and retrieve and check data using JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

How do I connect to MySQL database and retrieve and check data using JSP ?

I have been going through the tutorials in http://www.jsptut.com/Forms.jsp. There I see the setters and getters being set.

However I am not clear about how would I use them with MySql database. How do I add new users, retrive existing users ... from the database ?

I'm using Eclipse IDE. I have added the Tomcat the mysql-connector jar file in the project.

Comment: Beware: the tutorial you linked is extremely outdated.

Comment: You need a tutorial on using JDBC to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: Read this tutorial "[Getting Java, mySQL and Eclipse to work to-
gether](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:wIPhrY-np5AJ:www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2006/spring/10200-1/mysql/JDBC.pdf+mysql+database+java+example+on+eclipse&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShVQovDV9DyhDC4rnDzylAC1Xq_hdcXc-j9V-2yqiHZs-cT9MNCNyTKCKUwO1oN6gP4zkIMNEO1DJidKt4LUAHcDvNKLLZgJZrPqoFZ4wah1CcAVr67_hq1j69EQFGjnnurny27&sig=AHIEtbQgq54AmHcXTdtVext0qiUSfiAbcA)"

Comment: Are there any links using JSP that I could refer to ?

Answer (score 2):

Use can use following link to refer :[connect to mysql using jsp](http://www.9lessons.info/2008/09/jsp-login-page-to-connect-mysql-atabase.html).Also for tutorial refer sites like www.roseindia.net , mkyong.net and viralpatel.net